# DOM Ready vanilla javascript not working

Tags: javascript, dom, methods

My CS teacher insists that all JS has to be put in the `<head>` tags and nowhere else.  He also insists that we use only vanilla javascript without any libraries.  So in an effort to comply, I've created the following form with accompanying JS to validate it.  The problem is that when wrapped in the state change checker it doesn't work.  My code is below

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="script.js"></script> 

</head>

<body align="center">

<h2>Super Secret Login</h2>

<!--Added an onsubmit action to catch the form in case it isn't valid !-->

<form onsubmit="return j.validate()" name="myForm" action="http://sophist.cs.slcc.edu/~philn/cgi-bin/quick.cgi" method="post">UserID:
    <input name="userid" size="15" /> <!-- Remember closing tags on all elements !-->
    <br />
    <br />Password:
    <input name="password" size="15" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <center>
        <table cellspacing="20px">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function domReady() {

    var flag;
    var userid = document.myForm.userid;
    var pas = document.myForm.password;





    this.validate = function () {

        if (userid.value === "milton1" && pas.value === "k1mb3r")

        {
            flag = 1;
        } else if (userid.value === "shelly15" && pas === "4ng21") {
            flag = 1;
        } else {
            flag = 0;
        }



        if (flag === 0) {

            alert('There was a problem with your username and password');
            return false;

        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };


}






// Mozilla, Opera, Webkit 
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", arguments.callee, false);
        var j = new domReady();

    }, false);

    // If IE event model is used
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
    // ensure firing before onload
    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function () {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            document.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", arguments.callee);
            var j = new domReady();

        }
    });
}
```

Now without wrapping the whole thing in a function and calling the submit as a method this works, so long as I put the script at the bottom of the page.  Can someone help me understand why it does not work in this way?

Comment: your cs teacher is not a moron

Comment: People still use a CLEAR button on forms? Whatever for?

Comment: Is it not best practice that script tags be at the end of the page to ensure that the DOM is loaded?  And looking past my personal opinion of my CS teacher, any thoughts about the question at hand?

Comment: It's one way of doing it, certainly. Not always the best, though. And until you know (at least some of) the alternatives, you're not in any position to argue the merits, or complications. Learn the alternatives, you can never-use them after you've finished your education.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll keep interpretive language out of the discussion to facilitate a useful conversation, but does anyone know why this wouldn't work?

Comment: @richbai90, having script tags at the end of the page (read, right before `</body>`) isn't about DOM readiness, but preventing white-page syndrome.  Scripts in the head *can* block the rest of the page from loading, giving users a sense of lag.  Scripts towards the end allow the page to load more responsively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`j` is out of scope for the form's `onsubmit`. To use it with an inline event handler, it must be global, so you can't declare it inside the event listeners.

Change to:

```
var j;
// Mozilla, Opera, Webkit 
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", arguments.callee, false);
        j = new domReady();

    }, false);

    // If IE event model is used
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
    // ensure firing before onload
    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function () {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            document.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", arguments.callee);
            j = new domReady();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This proved to be the answer, I appreciate your help.  I still don't quite understand how the addEventListener works as I've never used it.  Forgive my arrogance in assuming there was one right way to do this. My CS teacher did not teach us how to do this either which is frustrating

Comment: The thing is: if you declare a variable inside a function, it's not visible outside that function. And you're passing a function to addEventListener. That's the root of the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Every time your browser see's an `<script>` tag, it runs it. When you load your `script.js` in the `<head>`, it runs it, and it tries to find your `<form>` that wasn't parsed yet, and thus **still doesn't exist**. So your `userid` and `pas` variables will be `undefined`.

To keep your code on the `<head>` and make it work the way you expect, you have to run your code when the DOM is ready.

The easy way to do this, is to define a callback that will be trigger after the document is loaded, like:

```
window.onload = domReady;
```